# Workaround for circular references between C++ classes

Tags: c++, pointers, include

Right now I have two classes which both have pointers to each other. When I try to compile it has an error because the program cannot compile one class without already having compiled the other.

It works like this

1. Main.cpp includes class A
2. Header guard for class A
3. Class A includes class B
4. Class B includes class A
5. Class A already got included so the header guard prevents loading it again
6. Class B has no idea what class A is

I just need to be able to reference one class from the other. I'm not incredibly skilled with C++ so this may be obvious but help would be appreciated.

Comment: If object `a` contains object `b` which contains object `a` you have an infinite object as this chain never finishes.  You need to break the nested object chain by using a pointer and then you can then forward reference the class declaration to break the `#include` chain.  I know this is a bit general; please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: The header for class A should not need the header for class B, instead use a forward declaration.  Likewise for class B and class A.

Comment: See C++ forward declaration. There are a couple of related posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration

Comment: If you have two classes that dependent on each other I have doubts your design is ok. You can have a look at dependency inversion to where you define interfaces between the classes and put them in their own header files.

Comment: If you can't solve it using this you will likely have to redesign: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: If the classes only have pointers to each other, then you don’t need their full declarations; forward declarations will do.